# Download the file without going to the reference site With Ajax& jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to have a site download form like this site. Enter the link in the input, go to the main site and download the link on the same page without going to the destination site. How can I do this with jQuery and AJAX? or Should I write server-side code?

```html
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="http://sci-hub.bz/">
  <input id="linkform"type="textbox" value="Please enter DOI / URL" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Please enter DOI / URL') {this.value = '';}" onblur=" if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Please enter DOI / URL';}" name="request">
  <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

1. Please go to this link: ardabil-sci.com/extrapage/shubframe
2. Enter this link in the input field: sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167739X17307835
3. I want the form I wrote above to act like this form. Download the article on same page from the reference site without going to the reference site

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed done serverside. You have to send an extra header to inform the browser to download the file, instead of directing the browser to it.

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: I do not know server-side programming, Can you say what to do in this particular case?